# How to convert hex value to a version number in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to get a version number of a software from the Windows Registry. Ideally I would like to see the version in the format of 2.0.3 but the version number I get is in decimal format 33554435.

I have tried converting the decimal number to hex number (which looks quite close to the version number 2.0.3) but I don't know how I can convert the hex number to the version number I desired. I read [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Convert decimal to hex and binary](https://soykablog.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/three-ways-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-powershell/) but I am stuck now. All I can think of is extracting the number 2, 0 and 3 so I can put them into a string but this is not ideal as it will not work properly if I update the software to a newer version. Any help is appreciated!

```bsh
PS> "{0:x8}" -f 33554435
02000003
PS> $CGVer = "{0:x8}" -f 33554435
PS> $CGVer = "0x" + $CGVer
PS> $CGVer
0x02000003
```

Comment: it may help others help you if you include the application in question.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thank you for the tip but the software is created by my company so I don't think it will help but if you go here `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products` and just choose any software, you will see the version number similar to what I have

Comment: i see what you are looking at now. thank you for the info! [*grin*] ///// however, it is NOT the usual place to get version info, from what i can tell. you want the uninstall key >> `dir 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'` << or the current user version. ///// for instance, the location you listed shows `Apple Software Update` with a version of `2060000` in hex. but the uninstall location shows `DisplayVersion : 2.6.0.1` & `Version : 33947648`. that last is DEC - when in HEX it shows `2060000`.

Comment: Why not just try if `Get-Command` returns the Version? `Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\your\*.exe | Get-Command`

Comment: @LotPings It is a msi and it does not have a executable (I can't find it in C:) :(

Comment: @Lee_Dailey not sure if it is because it is a private software but it is not showing in the directory `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products`

Comment: @JiaHao - that is not what i pointed you to ... [*grin*] instead, look in the **_uninstall_** section that i listed earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use `-band` and `-shr` operators to extract the proper bits from the hex number.

Here is an example you can modify as you see fit.

```
function Show-Version($ver)
{
    "-------------------------------------"
    "Showing version:" + $("{0:X8}" -f $ver) 

    "HEX"
    "{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0xFF000000) -shr 24)

    "{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0x00FF0000) -shr 16)

    "{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0x0000FF00) -shr 8)

    "{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0x000000FF) -shr 0)

    "DECIMAL"
    "{0}" -f (($ver -band 0xFF000000) -shr 24)

    "{0}" -f (($ver -band 0x00FF0000) -shr 16)

    "{0}" -f (($ver -band 0x0000FF00) -shr 8)

    "{0}" -f (($ver -band 0x000000FF) -shr 0)
}

Show-Version 0x22554435
Show-Version 0xa013fab # 10.1.63.171
Show-Version 0x01020304 # 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: From what I've seen the hex is split into 3 sections. MMmmbbbb where MM=Major, mm=Minor, and bbbb=Build. You might want to combine the last two into `$ver -band 0x0000FFFF`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks I was confused about that.

@KoryGill Thanks for the answer, just want to check if we take in @TheMadTechnician idea, should the statements look like this?

`"{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0xFF000000) -shr 24)
 "{0:x2}" -f (($ver -band 0x00FF0000) -shr 16)
 "{0:x4}" -f (($ver -band 0x0000FFFF))`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't like the repetitions in [@KoryGill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329137/kory-gill)s otherwise good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464896/6811411)(+1).

- a for loop couting down `3..0` should do the shifting multiplied by 8 also for the mask
- storing the 8bit values in an array
- outputtting the whole array directly with the `-format` operator
- creating a variant which combines the last 16bit
- returning a `[PsCustomObject]`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\02\SO_55464728.ps1
function Show-Version($version){
    $ver = @()
    for ($i=3; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
       $ver += (($version -band (0xFF -shl ($i*8))) -shr ($i*8))
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Input      ' = "{0:D}" -f $version
        'Version Hex' = "0x{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2}" -f $ver
        'Version Dec' = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $ver
        'mmMMbbbb'    = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $ver[0],$ver[1],($ver[2]*255+$ver[3])
    }
}

Show-Version 0x01020304 # 1.2.3.4
Show-Version 0x22554435
Show-Version 0xa013fab  # 10.1.63.171
Show-Version 33554435   # 2.0.3
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\02\SO_55464728.ps1

Input       Version Hex Version Dec mmMMbbbb
----------- ----------- ----------- --------
0x01020304  0x01020304  1.2.3.4     1.2.769
0x22554435  0x22554435  34.85.68.53 34.85.17393
0xa013fab   0x0a013fab  10.1.63.171 10.1.16236
33554435    0x02000003  2.0.0.3     2.0.3
```

Comment: Good answer.  Only thing missing might be adding/returning a `[version]` object which has Major/Minor/Build/Revision members.  That said, one can always `[version]::Parse` 'Version Dec' property. Guess it all depends with what a person wants to do with the data. Thx @LolPings.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer

Comment: Thanks  for the answer, I am not able to understand how it is working.If possible can you share some link  so that I can get  insight of this .Thanks in advance